# Cropping tool for 4:3 or 16:9 images with Preview.app?

Tags: preview, image-editing

Is there some trick to allow me to crop a screen shot in Apple's Preview.app to 4:3 or 16:9 dimensions?

I did notice holding down shift causes a 1:1 rectangular selection, but I need other common ratios.

I am willing to accept a solution from other lightweight tools.

Comment: What software are you talking about?

Comment: Image cropping software?

Comment: Did you answer my question or do you ask me another question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not use the Photos app for much, but I use it for this. I import the photo I want to crop. Click on the edit tool in the upper right and in the lower right you'll see "Aspect" with various options. You can crop to any of the desired ratios or customize a ratio. Once cropping is complete, I export the photo and delete it from Photos.

E.g., this makes it easy to crop a 4:3 digital photo to 16:9 for use as desktop.

Comment: Would appear I can't import PNGs to the Photos.App

Comment: Convert the PNG to JPEG. Open up the screen shot in Preview, hold down option key while selecting File menu, Save As... JPEG.

Comment: This was a super straightforward solution and worked great for me.

Comment: Which version of Photos are you using?  In Photos 4.0 in macOS 10.14 Mojave, after clicking on "Edit" I needed to click on the "Crop" tab on the top to bring up the aspect options, which were in the top right rather than the lower right.